# ERC721 Dynamic TokenURI on each tokenID

Tags: nft, erc-721

am new to solidity and would like to do some experimental on ERC721. I wish to link tokenURI for each tokenID differently based on action, and here is what i plan so far but got stuck in solidity format.

**Sample:**

User minted token ID 1 and 2 and both token ID point to "1a.json" and "2a.json"

User run the Action-A function using token 1, now i wish to point token 1 to "1b.json" and token 2 remain "2a.json"

```
string aUri = "a";
string bUri = "b";
string public _metadataURI = "https://path/to/json/";
//Here i wish to set status of all token = a as default

function setMetadataURI(string memory uri) external onlyOwner {
        _metadataURI = uri;
    }

function Action-A(uint256 tokenId) external {
        require(tx.origin == msg.sender, "error");
        //here is where i wish to set tokenId 1 status = b
}

function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        string memory baseURI = _metadataURI;

        if (status(tokenId) == a) {
            return bytes(aUri).length > 0
            ? string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, aUri, tokenId.toString(), baseExtension))
            : "";
        } elseif (status(tokenId) == a) {
            return bytes(bUri).length > 0
            ? string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, bUri, tokenId.toString(), baseExtension))
            : "";
        }
}
```